# Printing a list containing user defined objects returns addresses and implementing roots of complex numbers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

As part of trying to understand python, I am trying to implement complex numbers as part of understanding classes. I was trying to implement the **pow** magic method to return a set of complex numbers for rational powers and unique complex number for Integral power.

What I attempted was implementing the [De Moivre's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula) for Integral powers and its [generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula#Failure_for_non-integer_powers,_and_generalization) for rational powers.

```py
def __init__(self,real=0,imag=0):
        self.real=real
        self.imag=imag
def arg(self):
        return atan2(self.imag,self.real)
def __abs__(self):
        return sqrt(self.real**2+self.imag**2)
def __str__(self):
        if self.imag == 0: 
            return f'{self.real}'
        if self.real == 0: 
            return f'{self.imag}i'
        sign = '+' if self.imag>0 else '-'
        return f'{self.real}{sign}{abs(self.imag)}i'
def __pow__(self, b):
        if isinstance(b,int): 
            if b==0:
                return 1          
            r=abs(self)**b
            t=self.arg()**b
            self.real=r*cos(t) 
            self.imag=r*sin(t)
            return self
        else:
            roots=list()
            c=Fraction(b).limit_denominator()
            c,d=c.numerator,c.denominator
            tem=self**c
            r=abs(tem)**(1/d)
            t=tem.arg()
            for i in range(d):
                tem.real=r*cos((t+2*pi*i)/d)
                tem.imag=r*sin((t+2*pi*i)/d)
                roots.append(tem)
            return roots
```

What I expected was to receive cubic roots of unity for statements

```
a=complex(1,0)
print(a**(1/3))
```

but what i obtained was addresses for objects inside the list.

```
[<__main__.complex object at 0x02FCEBF0>, <__main__.complex object at 0x02FCEBF0>, <__main__.complex object at 0x02FCEBF0>]
```

on appending str(Tem)
I did get answers but incorrect as

```
['1.7099759466766968', '-0.8549879733383481+1.4808826096823642i', '-0.8549879733383492-1.4808826096823637i']
```

What I would like to understand is how I can have list entries be of type complex ( which i took as my class) and yet print them succesfully
and why am I getting an incorrect answer.

Comment: Just for what it's worth, a complex number implementation is built in to Python: `a = 1 + 0j; print(a**(1/3))`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I know it is, but I am trying to implement it myself just to get an understanding of python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement `__repr__()` in your `complex` class. While `str()` is used specifically when converting to a string, `repr()` is used in most other cases where you're printing an object. It could be as simple as

```
def __repr__(self):
    return str(self)
```

which will leave the repr looking the same as the string. Alternatively, you might want to make it more explicit in the `repr` that *this is a complex number* than just printing it, in which case you might do

```
def __repr__(self):
    return f"complex({str(self)})"
```

or something similar. It's up to you in how you want to handle it.